# Restart needed to reconnect Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt

I was just reading the Apple Thunderbolt Wiki and stumbled upon this:

> 25) If I eject a Thunderbolt device using the Taskbar tool or disconnect the Thunderbolt cable, can I reconnect it again without
>   restarting?
>
> No. A directly-connected Thunderbolt device that is removed with the
>   Taskbar tool or by disconnecting the Thunderbolt cable will not be
>   recognized until you restart the computer.

Is that really true? Does that mean I would have to restart my macbook, if I was connected in the morning, unplugged it, put it to sleep, then went to the office and wanted to work on afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only applies to using the Thunderbolt device under Windows 7. It's not the case when you're using OS X — you should be able to plug and unplug at will, without needing to restart.

It's not clear from that quote, but if you note, the index of [Apple's Thunderbolt FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219) (from which this nugget came), items 21 through 27 relate only to using Thunderbolt devices under Boot Camp and Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You are right, I didn't read it carefully enough.

Comment: It's easy to miss if you don't pay attention to the headings, just the questions. Glad I could help.