# Is there a way to use a Thunderbolt monitor with Bootcamp (WIndows 7) and not need to restart each time it's connected?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, display, windows, thunderbolt

So, I'm using a brand new Mac Book Pro with Bootcamp and Windows 7 and I have at giant 27" thunderbolt display.  The problem I'm having is at the office I take my laptop with me to meetings.  Upon returning, when I plug the monitor in (as I did with previous monitors) this one will not turn back on.  I am required to restart Windows each time which is, well, unacceptable.

Since the FAQ says that Bootcamp requires a reboot once the display has been ejected. I would like to spend money on hardware or time/money on software to get around this design limitation.

How can Windows and thunderbolt displays work the [same way as OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/restart-needed-to-reconncect-thunderbolt-display) with respect to not requiring an OS restart to reconnect the display?

Comment: Downvoted for less than minimal research. If you read the [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69819/24324) to the question you link to it states that this is not possible. At least according to Apple. You would need to reword your question acknowledging this info from Apple and gear the question more towards unofficial hacks.

Comment: Rather than close this as a duplicate, I'll edit it to be enough different that we can keep it open. Please edit it further if my guess as to your intent was wide of the mark...

Comment: If there are any hacks, I'd like to know as well. I'm going crazy having to reboot all the time, or, when I want to take a break, put the laptop to hibernate instead of sleep is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> Thunderbolt hot plug is supported under Windows 8 or 8.1 on all 2014 and later Mac computers.

No - if you run older OS or hardware. In that case, this appears to be something you have to live with. The options are running Windows in a virtual machine so that Apple’s OS X drivers handle the hot plug for you or interrupt your workflow to accommodate the Windows drivers. Sorry, but I've not seen any other options so far to address this.

Reference: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154